# Error: Cannot find module '@babel/types' when use npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject

Tags: reactjs, react-native

`I following the tutorial https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup to setup a reactive native project, but when i try the command:

```
npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject
```

I have the error :

`npx react-native@latest init agendaEscolar

```
Error: Cannot find module '@babel/types'
Require stack:
/home/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/@babel/helper-split-export-declaration/lib/index.js
/home/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/metro-source-map/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/scope/lib/renamer.js
/home/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/metro-source-map/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/scope/index.js
/home/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/metro-source-map/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/index.js
/home/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/metro-source-map/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js
/home/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/metro-source-map/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/traverse-node.js
/home/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/metro-source-map/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/index.js
/home/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/metro-source-map/src/generateFunctionMap.js
/home/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/metro-source-map/src/source-map.js
/home/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Serializers/sourceMapGenerator.js
/home/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Serializers/sourceMapString.js
/home/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/node_modules/metro/src/lib/getAppendScripts.js
/home/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Serializers/baseBytecodeBundle.js
/home/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js
/home/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/node_modules/metro/src/shared/output/bundle.flow.js
/home/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/node_modules/metro/src/shared/output/bundle.js
/home/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/build/commands/bundle/buildBundle.js
/home/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/build/commands/bundle/bundle.js
/home/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/build/commands/bundle/index.js
/home/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/build/commands/index.js
/home/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/build/index.js
/home/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/index.js
/home/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js
/home/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/bin.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1082:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:928:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:121:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/@babel/helper-split-export-declaration/lib/index.js:8:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1267:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1321:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1125:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:965:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
```

node -v
v20.1.0

npm -v
9.6.6

I try delete modules, reinstall node, install babel, and nothing work

i try to create a project with command

```
npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject
```

and i expected that React Native application have been created.`